How to train and test a weed detection algorithms using drone data
I have come across a weed database with labels and annotations for cotton weeds that was captured by a drone. Now I want to train and test the dataset which can be found here (Weed database). I do not necessarily come from a data science background so I have tried using Claude for help. However the results are very bad. What I would want to know which data to use for training since the database has several folders namely, the raw images, overlay folder (where polygons where drawn over the weed regions), the labels folder where crops and soil are removed so its a black background image only with the colord polygons indicating weed regions remaining) and the labels_1d folder which I do not know what it is about. More info is on this github page .

This depends on what exactly you're trying to do, but generally you'd use the data you would use as the input of your algorithm and the data that you would want your algorithm to predict.
